# C# - Get Second to Last Item in a List

Tags: c#

I have some code written in C#. In this code, I have a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> items`. I am trying to get the second-to-last item in the list. I'm having problems doing it though.

Originally, my collection was just a `Dictionary<int, string>`. At that point, I was using:

```
var nextToLast = items.Reverse().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

That worked. However, since `items` is now a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`, the `Reverse` method returns a `void`. So, I can't do the skip.

Anyone know of an elegant way for me to get the second-to-last item from a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` in C#?

I know I can use a loop. I just figured there had to be a better way.

Comment: use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` on your list

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have a `List<>`, so why not use its `Count` and indexer properties:

```
var item = items[items.Count-2];
```

Make sure that there are at least two items in the list though.

Comment: Thanks. Boy do I feel dumb. I was so focused on using LINQ that I totally overlooked the obvious. Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't handle the list having 0 or 1 items. The LINQ solution returns an empty IEnumerable.

Answer (score 33):

Starting with C# 8.0 you can use the `^` operator, which gives you access to the index from the end[[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator-).

So you can just do:

```
var item = items[^2];
```

More examples:

```
int[] xs = new[] { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 };
int last = xs[^1];
Console.WriteLine(last);  // output: 40

var lines = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
string prelast = lines[^2];
Console.WriteLine(prelast);  // output: three

string word = "Twenty";
Index toFirst = ^word.Length;
char first = word[toFirst];
Console.WriteLine(first);  // output: T
```

Answer (score 25):

Try this :

```
items.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: using this, doesn't the OP risk the following problem : Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable? Because of the AsEnumerable ? That could lead to unwanted memory leaks.

Comment: @KevinAvignon The `AsEnumerable()` essentially returns the `IEnumerable` interface of the  `List`, which allows us to calls the extension method `Enumerable.Reverse()` instead of `void List.Reverse()`. There is no chance of multiple enumeration. This is because the `IEnumerable` was never exposed, as we are returning a `T` (or, more specifically, a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`).

Answer (score 9):

You can use [ElementAtOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
items.ElementAtOrDefault(items.Count - 2)
```

Or [`Take`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj6wpDJvqrNAhVlGsAKHRWABPcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb503062(v%3Dvs.100).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGW82L1GnQgnBe-UPeiXdUTxjU0Iw&bvm=bv.124272578,d.ZGg&cad=rja) and [`LastOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
items.Take(items.Length - 1).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Needs second to last - so -2

Comment: @PaulF Thanks. Changed it to -2 :)

Comment: I think the second method is preferable as there is no need to check for at least 2 elements in the array. The first will cause an exception without a check.

Comment: @PaulF well, the first one is more readable then the second one. And both of them are faster then `Reverse`.

Comment: You might want to use `ElementAtOrDefault` just to be safe.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Thanks. `ElementAtOrDefault` suits better

Comment: Another alternative, could be `Skip(n-2)` with `FirstOrDefault()`. I believe, this could be slight faster than `Take+LastOrDefault`, since you won't be passing almost the entire list(minus 1element) around, but only 2. However, you might as well just use `ElementAtOrDefault` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IList<string> newList = new List<string>();
public void OnGet()
{
    var list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    list.RemoveAt(0);
    while (list.Count != 0)
    {
        var index = list.Next(0, list.Count);
        newlist.Add(list[index]);
        list.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

---

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        @Model.newList[0]
    <td>
    <br />
    <td>
        @Model.newList[1]
    <td>
    <br />
    <td>
        @Model.newList[2]
    <td>
    <br />
</tr>
```